# Scalaz equivalent to forM_

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I was just playing around a bit with `ST` in scalaz and came to the point, where I wanted to use the contents of a traversable type to modify my `STRef`. In Haskell I could do that as follows (taken from the Haskell wiki):

```
sumST :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumST xs = runST $ do

   n <- newSTRef 0

    forM_ xs $ \x -> do
        modifySTRef n (+x)

   readSTRef n
```

Unfortunately I have not been able to find the equivalent for `forM_` in scalaz. So the question is, how can I do this with scalaz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably know, `forM_` is a flipped version of `mapM_`.

You can use `traverse` and `traverse_` (which *are* implemented in Scalaz), as generalised versions of `mapM` and `mapM_`.

As proof, see that `Data.Traversable` exports its own implementation of `mapM`, in terms of `traverse`.

A scalaz version of `sumST` might look like this:

```
def sumST[S, A](as: List[A])(implicit A: Numeric[A]): ST[S, A] =
  for { n <- newVar(A.zero)
        _ <- as.traverseU(a => n.mod(A.plus(_, a)))
        m <- n.read } yield m

def sum[A : Numeric](as: List[A]): A =
  runST(new Forall[({type λ[S] = ST[S, A]})#λ] {
    def apply[S] = sumST[S, A](as)
  })
```

For readers wondering why it is so much more verbose than the haskell version: We must use the `Forall` trait to represent a rank-2 polymorphic type in Scala. See http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/towards-an-effect-system-in-scala-part-1/ for a fuller explanation.